# Separated network for layer 2 and 3 with additional wifi routers possible?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt, wifi-configuration, subnet

I need help in setting up a second isolated network for IoT stuff (TV, Fridge...). I tried it with two wifi routers, but when I tested it, it was not isolated yet. For the test I had the main router of the ISP and a second additional router connected from its WAN port to a free LAN port of the main router. Then I had one PC1 connected to the WIFI of the main router of the ISP, and a second PC2 connected to a LAN port of the second router.

My test if both networks/devices are separated from each other was according to this method:

> Establish the IP address of system 1. Have the the PC1 ping
> PC2 and while (or shortly after) this ping is in process on
> PC2, in a terminal or command window type "arp -an" . If the IP
> address on PC1 appears in the list of entries its on the same
> subnet.

Test failed, I could see the IP of the first system (PC1) during my test. It was surprising to me because both PCs were connected to different routers.

I have not done any configuration changes on both routers because I don't know what to change.

Can you give me instructions what changes in the configuration settings of the second router I should do exactly to establish an effective isolated second network (DHCP/subnets/IP/firewall/bridging)? The router is ddwrt compatible according to the ddwrt website. But I would prefer a solution without changing firmware. If a solution is only  possible with ddwrt then please explain a solution with ddwrt.

Comment: Interesting question. It would help very much if you included a picture showing the wiring

Comment: You write "I have not done any configuration changes on both routers because I don't know what to change. I just know bridging mode is available." <-- bridging mode would be worse 'cos bridging and switching are basically the same thing, meaning on the same subnet

Comment: I think you might need a router that lets you actually set up subnets in its configuration.....

Comment: A lot of basic "home routers" just have 2 sides, a WAN side and a LAN side, so mathematically how can you  get a tree like structure with just sticks and where you can't plug two things into one socket. I suppose You can't.  You need a router that includes configuration for multiple subnets.

Comment: Does this answer your question [security - Secure Home Network Partition for IoT Devices - Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/35/secure-home-network-partition-for-iot-devices)?

Comment: DavidPostill, that solution is not working, ping still possible, devices are visible to each other

Comment: hi @barlop, this is exactly what I am looking for, as highlighted in my question. I need an expert explaining how to change IP/Subnet configurations? Can you guide me thx (I don't know what kind of numbers to put in the subnet settings of both routers). and BTW: Subnet separation would only deliver layer 3 isolation. But not layer 2, correct? Or is subnet isolation enough to block communication/visibility among the different devices?

Comment: @anna The whole concept of a subnet is layer 3. . IP Addresses. A subnet has its own IP address.   Subnets wouldn't necessarily block communication, you'd need to use the firewall feature within the device they call a router/"router", in order to control what goes from one subnet to another.  When you browse to go to a website they aren't on your subnet but you can communicate with them. Likewise with subnets on your LAN, communication isn't blocked by default, you'd need do look at the/a firewall for that. But ARP won't see see anything on a different subnet.

Comment: @anna For layer 2 'isolation', that can even be within a subnet. I think that kind of thing is called a VLAN. So for example each port of a switch or groups of them, can be isolated in some way from others on the switch.  Really it effectively has a similar use to subnets, but with VLANs it's all at layer 2.

Comment: @anna For setting up subnets, that'd depend on the device or firmware on the device itself.  You can fiddle around with it and if you mess up then hit the reset button on it. Try finding out how to set subnets up with just one router first. And if you get stuck then you could ask on this site re that. and could include a pic of your router's config settings.. no security issue posting a pic showing 192.168 e.t.c. addresses (as 192.168 addresses are private and don't go out to the internet anyway ditto 10..x.x.x addresses)

Comment: hi @barlop, can you open a chatroom please to continue there? https://kb.netgear.com/30186/What-is-Double-NAT,  this link states that when having 2 routers like in my case, then I get effectively 2 separated private networks. They call it double NAT.  It seems this is achieved without any manual changes of subnets or IPs.  What do you say about this "double natting"? Can I go with that concept or do you suggest still to make manual subnet IP & Firewall adjustments?

Comment: According to that link double natting solves the layer 3 isolation issue (subnets). 
And now i have layer 2 issue left. You say it is best to use
the firewall settings for that. Please help me out what concrete changes
should I do in the firewall config? What rule(s) should I add to it?
Just use random numbers if you must use IPs for your answer. 
I will substitute with my numbers. Have no Screenshots now. @barlop

Comment: @anna Before you were talking about layer 2 and layer 3 and isolation(which is kind of theoretical), and now about just what is good security for IoT devices?  You don't need complete isolation and a firewall, for a reasonable level of security.. There is a superuser chat you could go into. Many people there can help.  Double NAT would be easier than a firewall and subnets. This looks like a good justification for double NAT https://blog.michaelamerz.com/wordpress/securing-a-network-for-iot/

Comment: hi @barlop, maybe it was not clear, but yes isolation is all about security. So that IoT devices cannot interfer with main home network.  can you finally confirm please: In your opinion, simply connecting another Router's WAN port with the main ISP router's LAN port, and enabling in both cases DHCP functionality - this setup would establish a double NAT AND TWO separated (on layer 3) private networks?

Comment: a @barlop, I just found this final issue with a 2-Router setup, can you please hint how this could be solved via manual router settings changes? I quote "2-router config works only if the ISP's main router does NOT forward requests it can't resolve to the gateway for it's own subnet (the ISP router must NOT check the WAN port for 192.168.1.2 for the two router configuration)" - "the "outer" LAN that is closer to the internet could read data coming from the "inner" LAN - 192.168.x.x IP's are non route-able for the internet, but "inner" router could let a "inner" PC access a "outer" PC via IP"

Comment: @anna, add the router make/models to the question please. This should be possible depending on the routers, but no one will be able to say for sure without more info.

Comment: @anna Been a while since I set up double NAT, and prior to IoT / some years back, the general advice was that double NAT was ugly.   But with IoT there is some justification for it. The justification being this line here https://blog.michaelamerz.com/wordpress/securing-a-network-for-iot/  "Even if any of those 'smart' devices is or becomes malicious, your devices behind the second ..[NAT device].. are out of reach"   As for the setup, I think there's nothing unusual done of connecting a WAN port to a LAN port.  The WAN port is connected to the wall. As in that diagram.

Comment: @anna  Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsE9OWQdtog a video where a guy does double NAT, see around 6:20  he says a cable connects the LAN port on one router to the LAN port on another. You write "enabling in both cases DHCP functionality"   No, you don't want DHCP on both otherwise you get a clash, you need to disable DHCP on one of them.

Comment: @anna  it's a good idea if you get your router from your ISP, then your ISP can talk you through it.   Or a router company like netgear actually have a tech support that can talk you through it.  Really that's the best way, even for tech people. It's a fiddly thing. They can talk you through it and explain stuff. And if you are an IT Technician,  then in future you will be able to do it yourself too. I don't know if you are an IT technician, but It's even fiddly for IT technicians.